# Do the flaws gained in suffering from multiple instances of Indefinite Madness stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, stacking, out-of-the-abyss, sanity

In *Out of the Abyss*, you gain levels of Madness due to certain events. Every time you fail, the Madness level increases, just like Exhaustion level:

- Level 1 Madness gives you Short term Madness - ~1 minute status effect
- Level 2 Madness gives you Long term Madness. - ~10 hour status effect
- Level 3 Madness gives you Indefinite Madness - Permanent Flaw

These can be cured as listed in the DMG, but in *Out of the Abyss*, when you gain another level of Madness while having level 3 Madness, your Madness level goes back to 1 then you go through all the levels again.

**What happens if the player gets into Level 3 Madness more than once, making him get multiple flaws due to Indefinite Madness?**

My plan was that, if the flaws stack, I think it will be hard to keep track of all the Flaws so I will just replace the old Flaw with the new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the description of [Madness Levels](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/oota/into-darkness#MadnessLevels) in *Out of the Abyss* (p. 21):

> If a creature with level 3 madness fails a madness saving throw, its madness level becomes 1. In this way, characters can potentially **accumulate multiple forms** of madness.

Yes, madness stacks. Since Indefinite Madness is well, indefinite, the flaw is retained when the madness level goes back to 1. In that case, a character would have 1 Short-term, and 1 Indefinite Madness going on.

Keeping track is as simple as writing down each Flaw gained under the old flaws. Though roleplaying multiple indefinite madness might be challenging.

As a sidenote, I wouldn't worry about getting too many stacks of Madness; when I ran the game a while back, only one player got his Madness up to 3, most of my players decided that 1 level was too much.

Comment: Thank god! I was worried if one player might get a LOT of flaws, and keeping track of it slows down the game. My players loves to roleplay so they might actually RP all the flaws they will gain.